# Magento 2 : Remove Top Links When Customer Not Logged In

Tags: magento2, layout, customer, toplinks, link

I would like to **remove `My Account` link from top links**, when customer is not logged in.

How do I **achieve it via XML layout files**?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without xml file also which will be easier for your task.
First step that you have to do is override header part and once its done apply some simple logic like by checking cx is logged in or not.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {//apply logic here}
```

Comment: You shouldn’t use the object manager to do this. 1. It’s wrong. 2. Full page cache will get in the way with it being header related.

Comment: @andyjones even though this is an old comment i need to set this straight for future readers 1. Objectmanager is indeed wrong to use. 2. Logged in is part of Magento's caching tags and full page caching won't affect is since it has full page caches for each state seperatly

Answer (score 0):

You can remove via overriding theme layout or xml file.

> app/design/frontend/Package/themename/Magento_Customer/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
    <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />           <!--for Create Account Link-->
    <referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true" />         <!--for My Account Link-->
</referenceBlock>
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: This will always remove My Account link, I need to remove it only when the customer is logged out

Comment: I need to display My Account  link only for logged in customer

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there are two ways to go about this, you can do it with XML but also at the same time you're able to also do this with a helper.

The First way through a helper requires modification of theme templates and also a module making for Magento.

So...

Create your module, call it what you will And add a **helper** file into

> Vendor\Module\Helper\Data.php

Inside this file you can use the following:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    private $httpContext;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
    }

    public function isLoggedIn()
    {
        $isLoggedIn = $this->httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
        return $isLoggedIn;
    }
}
```

This will then allow you in your frontend theme to use:

```
$helper = $this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helper\Data');

if($helper->isLoggedIn()):
 ...
 echo 'Customer is logged in';
 ...
endif;
```

This won't be affected by full page cache and means you can add this when and where you need.

**Second Option. The XML One.**

Again you'll need to create a module for Magento, but this time you're going to create a module that adds XML handles to the page. This one is a little more complicated than using the helper.

So in this one, we're going to create an **observer** to add the handles to the page if the customer is either logged in or logged out.

Our first observer:

> Vendor\Module\Observer\AddHandles.php

Will look like this:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;


class AddHandles implements ObserverInterface
{

    /** @var CustomerSession  */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * AddHandles constructor.
     * @param CustomerSession $customerSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSession $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the customer is logged in and if so add a layout handle
     * @param Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();

        if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('logged__in');
        } else {
            $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('logged__out');
        }
    }
}
```

Then inside of:

> Vendor\Module\etc\frontend\events.xml

We'll add the following to call the handles for the frontend.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="layout_load_before">
    <observer name="add_layout_handles" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\AddHandles" />
</event>
```

You'll then be able to use the xml files:

> logged__in.xml
>
> logged__out.xml

In your frontend veiw.